# Python. Telebot. Ошибка JSON

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота продажника. Сделал тестовую оплату в 1р. Оплачиваю, нажимаю "оплатить" и вылезает ошибка:

```
2020-07-23 20:13:26,464 (util.py:68 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "JSONDecodeError occurred, args=('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/probo/PycharmProjects/ScamShopBot/main.py", line 227, in callback_inline
    last_payment = functions.get_last_pay(config.qiwi_number, config.qiwi_token)
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\functions.py", line 20, in get_last_pay
    req = req.json()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/probo/PycharmProjects/ScamShopBot/main.py", line 248, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/probo/PycharmProjects/ScamShopBot/main.py", line 227, in callback_inline
    last_payment = functions.get_last_pay(config.qiwi_number, config.qiwi_token)
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\functions.py", line 20, in get_last_pay
    req = req.json()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\ScamShopBot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Вот сам код:

```
import config
import requests
import telebot
import functions
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
print("| Бот инициализирован.")


def send_in_group(text):
    if config.group_id != "":
        bot.send_message(config.group_id, text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(config.admin_id, text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    markup.row("Каталог")
    markup.row("Обратная связь")
    markup.row("Тестовая оплата")

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>Добро пожаловать в {}.</b>".format(config.BOT_NAME), reply_markup=markup,
                     parse_mode="HTML")

    DB = functions.DataBase()
    if DB.search_user(message.chat.id) == False:
        refka = message.text[7:]
        user_from_worker = str(message.from_user.username)

        # Без реффки
        if refka == "":
            send_in_group("Новый айди юзера - @{}".format(user_from_worker))

            DB.new_user(message.chat.id)

        # С реффкой
        else:
            send_in_group("Новый юзер от работника @{}, айди юзера - @{}".format(refka, user_from_worker))

            DB.new_user(message.chat.id, referer=refka)

            with open("baza.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write("@{} | @{}".format(refka, user_from_worker))

    DB.close()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["users"])
def all_users(message):
    if message.chat.id == config.admin_id:
        DB = functions.DataBase()
        users = DB.get_all_users()
        DB.close()

        for mes in users:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mes)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def messages(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    username = message.chat.username

    if message.text == "Обратная связь":
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Cвязаться с менеджером', url="t.me/{}".format(config.manager))
        markup.row(button)
        bot.send_message(chat_id,
                         "Возникли <b>вопросы?</b>\nНеобходима большая <b>партия снюса?</b>\n\nВоспользуйтесь кнопкой ниже для связи с менеджером.",
                         reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == "Тестовая оплата":
        link = functions.get_payment_link(config.qiwi_number, 1)

        file = str(chat_id) + "last_pay.txt"
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти к оплате', callback_data='payment', url=link)
        button1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОПЛАТИЛ', callback_data='check_test')
        markup.row(button)
        markup.row(button1)

        bot.send_message(chat_id,
                         "<b>Для проверки оплаты перейдите по ссылке ниже, и после оплаты нажмите ОПЛАТИЛ</b>\n\n<i>Сумма оплаты: 1 руб.</i>",
                         parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=markup)

        with open("history_payment/" + file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write("1")

    elif "Каталог" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = ["Alfa", "Arqa", "Blax", "Boshki", "Nictech", "Kurwa", "Taboo"]
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Текст для каталога", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Alfa" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.ALFA
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог альфы", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Arqa" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.ARQA
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог арки", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Blax" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.BLAX
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог блакса", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Boshki" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.BOSHKI
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог бошки", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Nictech" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.NICTECH
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог никтех", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Kurwa" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.KURWA
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог курвы", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "Taboo" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        element_list = config.TABOO
        for element in element_list:
            markup.row(element)
        markup.row("В меню")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Каталог табу", reply_markup=markup)

    elif "В меню" == message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        markup.row("Каталог")
        markup.row("Обратная связь")
        markup.row("Тестовая оплата")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "<b>Добро пожаловать в {}</b>".format(config.BOT_NAME), parse_mode="HTML",
                         reply_markup=markup)

    # оплата
    elif "|Цена:" in message.text:
        splitter = message.text.split("|")

        good = message.text[:10]
        sum = message.text[-3:]

        if sum < "200":
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте снова, или через пару минут.\n\nНаши специалисты уже начали поиск проблемы.",
                             parse_mode="HTML")
        else:
            link = functions.get_payment_link(config.qiwi_number, sum, good)

            file = str(chat_id) + "last_pay.txt"
            markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти к оплате', callback_data='payment', url=link)
            button1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОПЛАТИЛ', callback_data='check')
            markup.row(button)
            markup.row(button1)
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "Ваш заказ:\n<i>{}\n{}\n\n</i>Сумма оплаты: {}{}".format(splitter[0], splitter[1], sum,
                                                                                      config.A_T), parse_mode="HTML",
                             reply_markup=markup)

            with open("history_payment/" + file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(sum)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    chat_id = call.from_user.id
    file = str(chat_id) + "last_pay.txt"
    if call.data == "check":
        with open("history_payment/" + file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            sum = f.readline()


        last_payment = functions.get_last_pay(config.qiwi_number, config.qiwi_token)

        # Оплата прошла
        if str(last_payment["sum"]) == str(sum):
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "<b>Ваша оплата успешно получена!</b>\n\n Полученный нами адрес:\n<i>{}</i>".format(
                                 last_payment["description"]), parse_mode="HTML")
            send_in_group(
                "Получена оплата в размере - {}р от юзера @{} с chat_id {}".format(sum, call.message.chat.username,
                                                                                   chat_id))

            DB = functions.DataBase()
            DB.pay(chat_id, sum)
            DB.close()

        # Оплаты нет
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "<b>К сожалению, ваша оплата пока не дошла до нас.</b>\n\n <i>Как только вы убедитесь в том что оплата успешно проведена, нажмите</i> <b>ОПЛАТИТЬ</b>",
                             parse_mode="HTML")

    elif call.data == "check_test":
        with open("history_payment/" + file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            sum = f.readline()

        last_payment = functions.get_last_pay(config.qiwi_number, config.qiwi_token)

        # Получена тестовая оплата
        if str(last_payment["sum"]) == str(sum):
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "<b>Ваша оплата успешно получена!</b>\n\n Полученный нами адрес:\n<i>{}</i>".format(
                                 last_payment["description"]), parse_mode="HTML")
            send_in_group("Получена тестовая оплата в размере - {}р от юзера @{} с chat_id {}".format(sum,
                                                                                                      call.message.chat.username,
                                                                                                      chat_id))

            DB = functions.DataBase()
            DB.pay(chat_id, sum)
            DB.close()

        # Не получена
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id,
                             "К сожалению, ваша оплата пока не дошла до нас. Как только вы убедитесь в том что оплата успешно проведена, нажмите ОПЛАТИТЬ")


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код и ошибку нормально

Comment: @dIm0n ок, сделал

Comment: Вангую. В JSONDecoder попадает значение None `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`